# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, token, role, id}). If you meant to render a collection of children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am setting up a React app with a Rails backend. I am getting the error "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, token, role, id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

```js
//import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

// CSS
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'; // or 'antd/dist/antd.less'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

//Notify
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

//Component
import Navbar from './component/layout/Navbar';

//Router
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import UserRoute from './component/routes/UserRoute';
import AdminRoute from './component/routes/AdminRoute';


//Pages
import Login from './component/pages/auth/Login';
import Register from './component/pages/auth/Register';
import Home from './component/pages/Home';
 import AdminDashboard from './component/pages/admin/AdminDashboard';
import UserDashboard from './component/pages/user/UserDashboard';

//Redux
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

//functions
import { currentUser } from './component/functions/auth';


function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const idTokenResult = localStorage.token;
    //console.log('App', idTokenResult);
    if (idTokenResult){
      currentUser(idTokenResult)
      .then(res=>{
        //console.log('App', res)
        dispatch({
          type: 'LOGGED_IN_USER',
          payload:{
            name: {
              name: res.data.name,
              token: idTokenResult,
              role: res.data.role,
              id: res.data._id
            }
          }
        })
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }
  },[dispatch]);


  return (
    <div className="App">      
      <Navbar />
      <ToastContainer />
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}/>
          <AdminRoute exact path="/admin/dashboard" component={AdminDashboard}/>
          <UserRoute exact path="/user/dashboard" component={UserDashboard}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );

}

export default App;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to reproduce the issue on stackoverflow code snippet, or any live editor like codesandbox.

Comment: Usually this error is straight forward. One of your component render functions returns an object instead of html or string. You probably need to do `JSON.stringify(myReturnedObject)` somewhere in one of your render methods to prevent the error.